# Using jquery in laravel 6

Tags: jquery, laravel

Can I use jquery in laravel 6? Where I need to put script? When I put my_custom.js in public folder and then in blade calls to it `<script src="http://conf.lara/js/my_custom.js"></script>` , js in console return next .

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>   Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way you can use to use jquery in VueJS projects, you can `webpack.ProvidePlugin` to add jquery as a plugin in your `webpack.mix.js`, here is a code snippet.

```
module.exports = {
    .....
    plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery'
      });
    ]
}
```

After doing that you can use jquery anywhere in your source code

```
// in a module
$('#item'); // <= just works

jQuery('#item'); // <= just works
// $ is automatically set to the exports of module "jquery"
```

you can refer to this documentation
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The element you act upon with Vue should not contain any scripts, imagine you have an id named `vue-app` and you load Vue like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app'
});
```

Then everything inside `<div id="vue-app">` should not contain styles or scripts. Simply place them outside of that element.

Comment: Ok, understand. But what is the best practice to plug script?

Comment: Various methods, usually you simply do `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` in where `asset` is a helper function that points to your public directory (where `index.php` should be defined).

Comment: Sory, I not correctly write . I am already use asset in blade , in my question I wrote in script tags already parsed data. Js file is in public/js src. And when I load page, in browser dev tools I can find It. I am confuse why console returns me an error.

Comment: The error you posted above? If you read carefully it says "Vue warn" which means it is encountered by Vue. You need to move the script outside of your Vue instance.